# Can anybody help me to parse response returned in array format by making soap request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am having Soap web service that returns data in array like json format
Link for web service is [Here](http://catalog.gemcojewels.com/webservice/webservice.asmx?op=GetSuperCategory) and output is

```
[{"SuperCatId":"1","SuperCategoryName":"Victorian Jewelry","SuperCatImage":"1fe97.jpg"},{"SuperCatId":"2","SuperCategoryName":"Fine Jewelry","SuperCatImage":"0cc4b.jpg"}]
```

So my question is how should i get data from this web service should i use JSON or soap parsing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes if the responce is JSON then you need to parse thru a JSON parser.

The good tutorial can be found here,

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

---

**FYI**

soap is a protocol by which client and web service talks with each other. A soap message is basically an XML, to parse the soap message you need to use GDataXML or something similar.

Once, you extract your JSON responce from the SOAP message then you have to use JAONParser(above given tutorial).

If the web service you are using has exposed WSDL (assuming its a RMI and not RESTFul) then you can use online tool such as sudzc to create client stubz which does all parsing code for you.

Comment: [{"SuperCatId":"1","SuperCategoryName":"Victorian Jewelry","SuperCatImage":"1fe97.jpg"},{"SuperCatId":"2","SuperCategoryName":"Fine Jewelry","SuperCatImage":"0cc4b.jpg"}]                                                                    now how to get superCategory name & images??

Comment: @Amrita, The tutorial I gave you has everything in detail. Check th fetchData method.